# Linear trasformation and Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

Let $T\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a linear trasformation of $\mathbb{R}$ defined as $Tx:=ax+b$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\ne 0.$

We denote with $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ the Lebesgue $\sigma-$ algebra and we denote with $\lambda^*$ the Lebesgue outer measure. Let $E\in2^{\mathbb{R}}$, we must prove that

> **Proposition.** $T(E)\in\mathbb{\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})}$ $\iff$ $E\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$

I just proved that $$\lambda^*(T(E))=|a|\lambda^*(E)\tag1.$$

Regarding the implication $(\Leftarrow)$ there are not problems.

$(\Rightarrow)$ **Proof.** Suppose that $T(E)\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\lambda^*(Z)=\lambda^*(Z\cap T(E))+\lambda^*(Z\cap\complement T(E))$ for all $Z\in 2^{\mathbb{R}}$.

Therefore we have that $$\lambda^*(T(Z))=\lambda^*(T(Z)\cap T(E))+\lambda^*(T(Z)\cap \complement T(E)),$$ so
$$\lambda^*(T(Z))=\lambda^*(T(Z\cap E))+\lambda^*(T(Z\cap\complement E)).$$

Multiplying the members for $|a|^{-1}$ we have $$|a|^{-1}\lambda^*(T(Z))=|a|^{-1}\lambda^*(T(Z\cap E))+|a|^{-1}\lambda^*(T(Z\cap\complement E)),$$ for $(1)$ we obtain $$\lambda^*(Z)=\lambda^*(Z\cap E)+\lambda^*(Z\cap \complement E),$$ then $E\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}).$

**Proof 2.** Observe that $$\lambda^*(E)=\lambda^*(T[T^{-1}(E)])=|a|\lambda^*(T^{-1}(E)),$$ then $$\lambda^*(T^{-1}(E))=\frac{1}{|a|}\lambda^*(E)\tag2.$$

Let $T(E)\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ then $\lambda^*(Z)=\lambda^*(Z\cap T(E))+\lambda^*(Z\cap\complement T(E))$, therefore $$\lambda^*(T(Z))=\lambda^*(T(Z\cap E))+\lambda^*(T(Z\cap\complement E)).$$ Now, $$\frac{1}{|a|}\lambda^*(T(Z))=\frac{1}{|a|}\lambda^*(T(Z\cap E))+\frac{1}{|a|}\lambda^*(T(Z\cap\complement E)),$$ then for $(2)$ we have $$\lambda^*(T^{-1}[T(Z)])=\lambda^*(T^{-1}[T(Z\cap E)])+\lambda^*(T^{-1}[T(Z\cap\complement E)])$$ and so  $$\lambda^*(Z)=\lambda^*(Z\cap E)+\lambda^*(Z\cap \complement E),$$ then $E\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}).$

Thanks!

> **Question** Are the proofs correct?

Comment: I know I should read your proofs cause that's what you asked about, but I feel obligated to point out that if $\Leftarrow$ is obvious, then $\Rightarrow$ is as well. Indeed, $E = T^{-1}(T(E))$, where $T^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{a}x-\frac{b}{a}$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: @mathworker21 thanks for your answer. So you say you use the previous point. That is first I prove that if $E\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})\Rightarrow T(E)\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$. On the other hand if $E\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$, since $T^{-1}$ is a linear trasformation for the previous point $T^{-1}[T(E)]=E\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}).$ Right?

Comment: I think you got it. Just to be sure we're on the same page: you prove $F \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \implies S(F) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ for a measurable set $F$ and linear transformation $S$. You then apply this with $F = T(E), S = T^{-1}$.